# Opposite of "dim the light"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

I was trying to figure out how to say something like "**|undim| the light**" in the meaning of "**restore the previous amount of light**" as an opposite of "**dim the light**" but have no idea what word or phrase I should use.

I was thinking of "**brighten**" but it implies a different feel to the phrase, something like "**make it brighter than it is now**".

The dictionaries give so many antonyms to **dim** and its synonyms *(like dull, faint, darken, subdue)* that makes it even harder to choose.

Comment: "Brighten" sounds like the most likely answer to me. What is this "different feel to the phrase", or why do you think "brighten" doesn't work?

Comment: @Max it seems to me that "**brighten the light means make it more bright then it is and that is impossible even if it's dimmed.**"

Comment: You're saying that it is impossible because of physical properties, or because the verb "brighten" doesn't allow it? Also, what's the context (to be clear)? Like a fire, a lamp, or light bulb?

Comment: @Max any of those three will do. You can dim by dulling the light bulb or the lamp or by putting out a few candles. But how to restore the previous amount of light?

Comment: @P.E.Dant The question is not about how to use the word **dim** but what to use as an opposite of dim in the context of any kind of light.

Comment: When I lower the light in a room, I _dim the light._ A dull-witted person is referred to as a _dim bulb._ These two examples may help you to grasp how we use "dim" in English. The opposite expression is _to brighten_ or _to turn up_ the light. Of the two, _turn up_ is most common. Most native USAian speakers wouldn't say _"dim the light,"_ anyway; they would say _"turn down the light."_

Comment: "But how to **restore** the **previous** amount of light?" I think you should include this in your question, as it might be what gives you a "different feel" when you hear brighten. As it seems, you don't want to "have more light" but instead "as much light as was before dimming it".

Comment: I found "**bring the light back up**" but I am unsure whether it really means what I want.

Comment: *Bring {light, sound, etc} back up* does indeed mean to restore it to its previous higher level.  **back** refers to a previous state.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So it does mean "**restore to a previous state**"?

Comment: **back up** means restore the thing (light, sound) to its previous higher intensity or level. Not sure why you're getting hung up on "state". "Bring the light back up to *where* it was."  It is not a precise/scientific locution.  *where* there refers to its level/intensity, not its physical location.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo What about *turn the light back up*? Somehow I think that *bring back up* implies that it's been completely shut off or nearly completely dimmed down, so you need to *bring* the light *back*, because there's an obvious absence of it.

Comment: @userr2684291:  **turn ... back up** works (even if it is a slider switch and not a twist knob);  **back** appears in both and it is **back** which suggests  *a degree of departure* from the prior state.  I don't think **bring** intensifies that degree of departure any more than **turn**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how exactly the state of the brightness of the lights needs to match the pre-dimmed state, and what level the brighter setting is. I.e. if you just want the lights set brighter than they currently are, or to be set to the highest brightness setting, you can be less specific in your instruction.

My choice for a less specific instruction would be (as mentioned in several comments):

> **turn up the lights / turn the lights up** - *if the lights were not previously set lower/if the lights being previously set lower is irrelevant*
>   **turn the lights back up** - *if the lights were previously dimmed*

The second of these gives the implication of returning to a previous state, but doesn't explicitly say that it must be to *exactly* the previous state.
*Turn* is especially suitable if it is a rotating dimmer switch

If there is a *specific setting* for the lights to be returned to (e.g. going from 1/4 brightness to 1/2 brightness, or changing to half of the lights at full brightness, half of the lights at 1/2 brightness) then you need to be more specific about it. Words like **reset**, **restore**, **return** or **redo** may be appropriate.
Note, however, that these terms do not specify that the lights are to be brightened.

Also note that just saying:

> do the lights

may well be understood in the context. It can also be used to mean *dim the lights*; for example before a slideshow you could say "do the lights" to mean *dim the lights* and afterwards also say "do the lights" to mean *make the lights bright again*.

Answer (score 1):

I have found "**bring the light back up**" which means "**restore it to a previous condition**".

As **@Tᴚoɯɐuo** commented, **back** refers to a previous state.

On the other hand "**[restore](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restore)**" *(to bring back to or put back into a former or original state)* seems to fit too.

Comment: +1 for 'bring the lights back up'.  In a film studio setting you'd normally hear 'lights'.  If they were currently dimmed this would mean 'bring them back up again'.  And if they were bright this would mean 'dim them'.  You can even say 'undim'.